# AttributeError: 'PositionalEncoding' object has no attribute 'position'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, chatbot, transformer-model

I am unable to understand that why i am getting this error.Code is working fine without saving the model but when i run `model.save()` it throws exception.
**Error is**

> AttributeError:Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 1 model.summary()
> 2 model.save('/content/Data/chatbot_model',include_optimizer=False)

> in get_config(self)

```
  9         config = super(PositionalEncoding, self).get_config()
 10         config.update({'position': self.position,
 12             'd_model': self.d_model,
 13
```

> AttributeError: 'PositionalEncoding' object has no attribute 'position'

**Here is the class code of Positional Encoding Class**

````
 def __init__(self, position, d_model):
   super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
   self.pos_encoding = self.positional_encoding(position, d_model)
 
 def get_config(self):

       config = super(PositionalEncoding, self).get_config()
       config.update({
           'position': self.position,
           'd_model': self.d_model,
           
       })
       return config

 def get_angles(self, position, i, d_model):
   angles = 1 / tf.pow(10000, (2 * (i // 2)) / tf.cast(d_model, tf.float32))
   return position * angles

 def positional_encoding(self, position, d_model):
   angle_rads = self.get_angles(
       position=tf.range(position, dtype=tf.float32)[:, tf.newaxis],
       i=tf.range(d_model, dtype=tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, :],
       d_model=d_model)
   # apply sin to even index in the array
   sines = tf.math.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])
   # apply cos to odd index in the array
   cosines = tf.math.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

   pos_encoding = tf.concat([sines, cosines], axis=-1)
   pos_encoding = pos_encoding[tf.newaxis, ...]
   return tf.cast(pos_encoding, tf.float32)

 def call(self, inputs):
   return inputs + self.pos_encoding[:, :tf.shape(inputs)[1], :]```
````

Comment: Please attach full stacktrace as it will have information of whole call sequence and exact line causing error.

Answer (score 0):

`position` and `d_model`  are not defined as attributes in `__init__` method and are not updated in any of the methods.