# Save tf model in colab to drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, google-colaboratory, checkpoint

I have trained a tensorflow model for chatbot using Transformers in colab and now I am trying to save the model.
I have mounted the drive and tried saving the model using the following.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

model.save("Cornell_Chatbot")
```

But it keeps me throwing out this error.

```
AttributeError: 'PositionalEncoding' object has no attribute 'position'
```

Why this happens and how can I save my trained model?

EDIT:

Try 02 (TENSORFLOW CHECKPOINT)

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

#Create checkpoint callback
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS,
          callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

I have tried with tensofrflow checkpoint. I am using TPU to run the model. This gives me the following error:

```
UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: 'training_1/cp.ckpt_temp_44208607b0084dbcacbf799c6eb30c94/part-00000-of-00001')
```

I hope this occures since Cloud TPUs can only access data in GCS. Am I correct?
How can I overcome this?

Comment: Once you mount your Google drive, you can copy the file from Colab  to google drive using the below command  

cp /content/model.h5    /content/gdrive/My\ Drive.                                                                     
                                                                                                                                           
The attribute error seems to be model issue. Attached similar SO issue for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586645/attributeerror-positionalencoding-object-has-no-attribute-position